# Is the HTML Help Workshop still a viable choice for use with applications?

Tags: asp.net, wpf, chm, html-help, help-system

I am trying to plan the Help function for a new application (desktop WPF, but also asp.net website).  I spent some time trying to research this and there doesn't seem to be a lot of information.  I have seen a variety of [solutions such as here](http://www.create-chm.com/chm-creation-tools/), but thought it best to ask for assistance from this forum before proceeding.

Is the [Microsoft HTML Help Workshop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms670134(v=vs.85).aspx) still a good way to go?  Is there some particular Help System solution that is preferred by a lot of people, or is it a situation where as many programmers as there are there are solutions?

Comment: There are far too many options these days, and it would be too general a question on which way should go. If you do force yourself to choose CHM as output, HTML Help Workshop definitely can work, as well as many third party solutions (many use HHW as output engine).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTMLHelp (HH) also known as Compiled Help Modules (.chm) is 20 years old but available and running on Windows 10. The runtime ships with Windows 95 and greater. Microsoft have created other help systems since HTML Help (.chm) but they are tied to various systems.

HTMLHelp is in "maintenance mode" for several years now. No new features are expected, and only critical updates will occur from now on. As far as I know there is no new help systems being developed at Microsoft.

You can spend a lot of money on "bells and whistles" tools that simplify and streamline the process of creating help files. Before you do so, it is worth trying out a few freeware tools.

Some thoughts:

- CHM's are good for application help.
- More and more content is web-based.
- Help authoring has a learn curve.
- Making good help topics is time consuming.
- You need one single-source and create e.g. CHM's and web-based help.

By the way, HTML Help Workshop (HHW) is not for use with applications but the tool for compiling CHM's. For beginners the GUI of HHW is somewhat difficult. The internals of HHW are required for compiling and used by many third party tools.

As a first step I'd recommend to create some simple HTML files and images. Have a look at [FAR HTML](https://www.help-info.de/download.html) - the wizards are great and web-based help is possible.

One tip - don't look at all the options of FAR when starting.

1. Put your HTML files to structured subfolders of your project folder e.g.

   welcome.htm
   design.css
   First_Steps\download.htm
   First_Steps\starting_program.htm
   How_to_extend\extend_menu.htm
   How_to_extend\power_function.htm
   images\gui_screenshot.jpg
2. Drag and drop these files to FAR
3. Start the wizard for HTMLHelp 1.x see main menu: Authoring > Help Wizard
4. ready ..

Try to connect the CHM generated by FAR HTML and your application.  /or web-based help generated by FAR HTML to your application. Check it for the customers view and your needs. Viewing CHM files that are stored on a network drive is difficult.

Comment: FWIW... FAR HTML has closed shop and is offering [free downloads and license keys](http://www.helpwaregroup.com/purchase/codes) until the website goes down. While obviously we can't know how much longer the hosting will last, the domain expires Apr 27, 2021. Sad to see them go... I was always fond of them.